# R: reshape 2 - colsplit not working with a period/fullstop

Tags: r, reshape2

I am trying to use the reshape2 package and the colsplit to separate at the "." pattern in a vector of strings. Usually it is a straightforward function but for some reason it is not working for me today.

If I try to use a different pattern it works fine. I am not exactly sure how the function works but I tried escaping it like you would in regex but that just through up errors although admittedly I am not very good with them.

Here is a MWE. How can I overcome this?

```
library(reshape2)

data <- c("Medtr0001s0360.1", "Medtr0001s0430.1", "Medtr0001s0490.1", 
"Medtr0001s0570.1", "Medtr0001s0570.2", "Medtr0001s0570.3")

GO_terms <- colsplit(data, pattern=".", c("a", "b"))
GO_terms
   a               b
1 NA edtr0001s0360.1
2 NA edtr0001s0430.1
3 NA edtr0001s0490.1
4 NA edtr0001s0570.1
5 NA edtr0001s0570.2
6 NA edtr0001s0570.3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the `"."`:

```
> GO_terms <- colsplit(data, pattern="\\.", c("a", "b"))
> GO_terms
               a b
1 Medtr0001s0360 1
2 Medtr0001s0430 1
3 Medtr0001s0490 1
4 Medtr0001s0570 1
5 Medtr0001s0570 2
6 Medtr0001s0570 3
```

---

From the help page at `?colsplit`:

```
pattern: regular expression to split on
```

Since the "pattern" argument is a regular expression, and since `.` is a special character in regular expressions, you will need to treat it as such.

Comment: Or use `pattern="[.]"`

Comment: @akrun What's the difference between "[.]" and "\\." ?

Comment: @Sescopeland  The `.` is a metacharacter which means any character.  So, to get the literal meaning of `.`, we either use escape (`\\.`) or place it inside the square brackets which will evaluate it as `.` or in some functions you can use `fixed = TRUE` with `.`